# How do dashes work in regex?

Tags: regex

I'm curious on the algorithm for deciding which characters to include, in a regex when using a `-`...

```
Example: [a-zA-Z0-9]
```

This matches any character of any case, a through z, and numbers 0 through 9.

I had originally thought that they were used sort of like macros, for example, `a-z` translates to `a,b,c,d,e` etc.. but after I saw the following in an [open source project](http://github.com/holman/bubs),

```
text.tr('A-Za-z1-90', 'Ⓐ-Ⓩⓐ-ⓩ①-⑨⓪')
```

my paradigm on regex's has changed entirely, because these are characters that are not your typical characters, so how the heck did this work correctly, i thought to myself.

My theory is that the `-` literally means

> Any ASCII value between the left character, and the right character. (e.g. a-z [97-122])

Could anybody confirm if my theory is correct? Does the regex pattern in-fact calculate using the character codes, between any character?

Furthermore, if it IS correct, could you perform a regex match like,

```
A-z
```

because `A` is `65`, and `z` is `122`  so theoretically, it should also match all characters between those values.

Comment: Try it: http://rubular.com/r/ULLy143jQu

Comment: It does, that is the reason people use `A-Za-z` rather than `A-z` (so they don't get the stuff between `Z-a`

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: I'm sure you're already aware of this, but for anybody else who reads this question, you can always use the case insensitive flag to match both sets of characters (e.g. `/[A-Za-z]/` can be written as `/[a-z]/i`.

Comment: @ctn - I believe the OP is looking for some documentation, etc, to absolutely confirm that this is the defined behavior and not some fluke in a particular engine.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 you are absolutely correct.

Comment: in fact - that's why i had tagged "theory" in the question, because right now - it's all theory, i haven't actual regular expression code to confirm my theories

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN - Character Classes in Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx) (bold is mine):

> The syntax for specifying a range of characters is as follows:

```
[firstCharacter-lastCharacter]
```

> where `firstCharacter` is the character that begins the range and `lastCharacter` is the character that ends the range. A character **range is a contiguous series of characters** defined by specifying the first character in the series, a hyphen (`-`), and then the last character in the series. **Two characters are contiguous if they have adjacent Unicode code points.**

So your assumption is correct, but the effect is, in fact, wider: **Unicode character codes, not just ASCII.**

Comment: `Two characters are contiguous if they have adjacent Unicode code points.` - that's pretty much what i wanted to hear. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Both of your assumptions are correct. (therefore, technically you could do `[#-~]` and it would still be valid, capturing uppercase letters, lowercase letters, numbers, and certain symbols.)

[ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif)

You can also do this with Unicode, like `[\u0000-\u1000]`.

You should not do `[A-z]`, however, because there are some characters between the uppercase and lowercase letters (specifically `` [, \, ], ^, _, ` ``).

Comment: yea - i see that. `], [` and a couple of others

Comment: Putting ASCII table in the answer isn't needed, you could just have given a link.

Comment: Thanks Doorknob, I appreciate the answer! This sheds some light on it.